# Homepage starts to lag because of javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, lag

I'm making a hobby webgame. It uses a **setInterval loop** that plays every **0.25 sec** to walk through a lot of statements. After playing the game actively for 10 minutes it starts to **lag a lot**. I can't figure out why, but maybe anyone of you can figure it out? I would be very thankfull. Here's the link to the website where I store the game http://blog.gilladesign.se/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! generally speaking, links to sites are generally a bad idea as they tend to dry up. Try setting up the code here in the question (a minimal, complete example [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] ) and link to a codepen or a fiddle.

Comment: Alright I'll set up a fiddle then.